# Differences between the results in Browser and HTML-View in Development-tools

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a webapplication in asp.net mvc 5. I call a View from a action.
But this view is not displayed. In the developer-tools ( FF and Chrome) I can see a correkt answer in the html-Tab. But not in the browser. 
Can anybody explain that?
Thats what is displayed:
[Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZexFU.png)

thats the answer in html-Tab of the dev-tools:

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syCD3.png)
Many thanks for your help
P

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this Action / View via an AJAX call? Since you are using a Grid I would be inclined to think that is likely.

If so, you'll want to ensure that you are actually setting the results of your contents within the callback function :

```
// Call a controller action via an AJAX call
$.ajax('controller/action', { id: 42 }, function(results){
      // results should be your actual View HTML
      $('#result-area').html(results);
});
```

If you are using some type of third-party components for performing this, there should be some documentation for how to handle your callbacks from your Controllers.